# Download using WebClient throw error 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: vb.net, webclient

i'm trying to download a file from url using this code :

```
Private Sub getPatch()
    Using client As New WebClient
        Dim url As String = My.Settings.host & "/update.zip"
        If Directory.Exists(Replace(fName, "\update.zip", "")) Then Directory.Delete(Replace(fName, "\update.zip", ""), True)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Replace(fName, "\update.zip", ""))

        AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf ProgressChanged
        AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf DownloadFileCompleted
        client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(url), fName)
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Try
        If e.ProgressPercentage = 100 Then Exit Sub
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub DownloadFileCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
    If Not e.Cancelled AndAlso e.Error Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Download success")
        extractZip(fName)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Download failed")
    End If
End Sub
```

whenever download complete (the files is successfully saved to my drive), it always throw error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

i try to debugging it, but it never fire DownloadComplete method.

[image: after error message, vs goes to this screen]

Comment: Change your `DownloadFileCompleted`, substitute `ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs` with `ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs`

Comment: thanks @Jimi , it's works now !

Comment: @Jimi , [DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloaddatacompletedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) inherits from AsyncCompletedEventArgs.

Comment: You may have a race condition where the `Using client` block disposes the WebClient before it is fully completed running.

Comment: @TnTinMn i changed without 'Using client', it's still error, but i tried Jimi solution and it works fine. Why is that ?

Comment: @XMozart, I don't know why it works.  I would declare `client` at the class level and assign it a new WebClient in `getPatch`.  Then call client.Dispose in `DownloadFileCompleted`.

Comment: @TnTinMn  It's the delegate signature that doesn't match. Option Strict off hides it.